# Take data from an existing CSV, manipulate the date format, and write it into a new CSV

Tags: python, csv

I just started to learn python so that I could make a program that could manipulate bank statement cvs files, but I do not know very much. I have one csv file with a column of dates in the format: month+day+year. Examples include 3/3/20, 12/2/20, 9/13/20, etc.

I would like to take these dates from the column and reformat them into the format: year+month+day. Examples of the format that I need them to be in include 200303, 201202, 200913, etc.

But I do not know how to get information from my original csv file and proceed to reorder it and write it into my new csv file. I am going to need a lot of explaining of the steps because I am so new to this. All help is appreciated though :)

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
        bank_statement = '/Users/annamobley/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Python/3 March 2020.csv'
# import initial bank statement
import csv

with open(bank_statement, 'rt')as initial_file:
    data = csv.reader(initial_file)
    for row in data:
        original_dates = str(row[1])

# find number of rows in the initial bank statement
file = open(bank_statement)
reader = csv.reader(file)
lines = len(list(reader))
num_lines = int(lines) - int(1)

# variables in new csv
upload_statement = 'manip_bank_statement.csv'
bank_abbreviation = "GCB"
acc_num = input('Enter the account number : ')
acc_name = input("Enter the Account Name/Description (): ")
# date format manipulation
first_2_num_year = input(
    "Input the first two numbers in the year that it is currently. Ex: If it is the year 2019, input '20': ")
import datetime as dt

post_date_original = row[1]
manipulated_date = (dt.datetime.date(dt.datetime.strptime(original_dates, '%m/%d/%y')).strftime('%y%m%d'))
final_date = str(first_2_num_year + manipulated_date)
# writing the new csv
import csv

with open(upload_statement, 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    for somevariable in range(num_lines):
        writer.writerow([bank_abbreviation, acc_num, acc_name, final_date])
```

I get the error message:

```
        Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/annamobley/PycharmProjects/CSV_Manipulation_Project/Project.2.redo.py", line 41, in <module>
    manipulated_date = (dt.datetime.date(dt.datetime.strptime(original_dates, '%m/%d/%y')).strptime('%y%m%d'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/_strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/_strptime.py", line 352, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 19
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a number of issues with your code.

For starters, here:

```
with open(bank_statement, 'rt')as initial_file:
    data = csv.reader(initial_file)
    for row in data:
        original_dates = str(row[1])
```

For each row in data, you give `original_dates` the string value of the 2nd column in the data, but you don't do anything with it, so it just gets overwritten for each record.

The next bit:

```
file = open(bank_statement)
reader = csv.reader(file)
lines = len(list(reader))
num_lines = int(lines) - int(1)
```

Here you reopen and reread the file, to get the number of lines - you could have gotten that number from the first time and subtracting 1 from an integer value is much simpler: `lines -= 1`

You then proceed to set up some values and perform the operation you really want:

```
manipulated_date = (dt.datetime.date(dt.datetime.strptime(original_dates, '%m/%d/%y')).strftime('%y%m%d'))
```

That's close, but if you'd use `%Y` instead of `%y`, you'd get the full year and you can avoid the whole business of adding `20` or `19` manually. See here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

You then proceed to write a new file, not really using any of the data from the old file. I assume you only want to update the date, so you could just reuse the data you already read from the old file. If there's more changes you want to make to the old data, you should make that clear in your question.

Here's a simple example of a program that does what you say you want:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime
# try to keep all your imports at the top, they're good all through the script

# setting up variables like these at the start is also a good idea, 
# especially when your script gets longer
bank_statement = '/Users/annamobley/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Python/3 March 2020.csv'
upload_statement = 'manip_bank_statement.csv'

# using with is a good idea, it automatically closes and releases the file
with open(bank_statement, 'r') as input_file:
    cr = csv.reader(input_file)
    # opening the new file here, we only need both files for one loop
    with open(upload_statement, 'w', newline='') as output_file:
        cw = csv.writer(output_file)
        # this line just copies a header from in to out
        # if your data has no header, just remove this line
        cw.writerow(next(cr))
        # loop over all the data in the reader once
        for row in cr:
            # on every row, assuming the 2nd columns has the date, replace it
            row[1] = datetime.strptime(row[1], '%m/%d/%y').strftime('%Y%m%d')
            # and write the result to output
            cw.writerow(row)
```

That's all, really.